# how to get the LinkedList address from other void functions

Tags: c, list, function, pointers, linked-list

1. I want to reverse the linked list for giving head pointer argument to reverse2 function.
2. I expect that the reverse2 function reverse the linkedlist and substitute the address to  head pointer

```
    //linked list//
    
    typedef struct node* lsnode;
    typedef struct node 
    {
        int data;
        lsnode link;
    }node;
    
    
    //create the 3 nodes
    
    lsnode create3() 
    {
        lsnode first, second, last;
     
        first = (lsnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
        second = (lsnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
        last = (lsnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
        first->data = 30;
        first->link = second;
        second->data = 20;
        second->link = last;
        last->data = 10;
        last->link = NULL;
    
        return first;
    }
    
    //reverse the linkedlist
    void reverse2(lsnode head)
    {
        lsnode q,p,r;
        p = head;
        q = NULL;
        r = NULL;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            r = q;
            q = p;
            p = p->link;
            q->link = r;
        }
        head = p;
    }
    
    
    int main(void)
    {
        lsnode head = create3();
        reverse2(head);
        while (head)
        {
            printf("%d\n", head->data);
            head = head->link;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

the program prints the only 30 but, I want to print 10 20 30
what's the problem with my code..

Comment: First: get rid of the `typedef`s; they are only confusing.

Comment: As usual when dealing with things like linked lists, I recommend you try to visualize all your operations using pencil and paper first. Draw a simple linked list using labeled squares for the nodes and other variables, and arrows for all pointers and links. When performing an operation erase and redraw the related arrow. Once you get it to work on paper write the code to implement that.

Comment: `reverse()` changes the head value of its *local* argument. The caller does not see this.

Comment: C  is pass by value. head is a copy

Comment: And using pencil and paper is also very useful when [*debugging*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program. Again draw your created list on paper. Then as you step through the code, statement by statement, while monitoring variable and their values, you erase and redraw arrows just like the program is doing it. That should make it very easy to notice when something wrong happens.

Comment: @wildplasser `typedef struct node* lsnode;` creates confusion, but the other one is OK for me.

Comment: Is it your intent to _reverse_ the order of nodes in the list or to search the list by traversing it from last node to first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some of the suggestions in comments, the following modifies the `reverse2` function to pass the address of the object being changed, as opposed to the object itself, allowing the modified object to be referenced in the calling function upon its return.  Regarding @Some programmer dude's suggestions on the value of visualization, I found [this to be helpful](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/).
Also, to make the code easier to follow, this code expands the single letter variable names to symbols that can be more easily understood by anyone reading the code.

```
typedef struct node* lsnode;
typedef struct node 
{
    int data;
    lsnode next;//changed from link
}node;


//create the 3 nodes

lsnode create3() 
{
    lsnode first, second, last;
 
    first = (lsnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
    second = (lsnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
    last = (lsnode)malloc(sizeof(node));
    first->data = 30;
    first->next = second;
    second->data = 20;
    second->next = last;
    last->data = 10;
    last->next = NULL;

    return first;
}

//reverse the linkedlist
void reverse2(lsnode *head)//changed prototype, 
{
    //lsnode q,p,r;
    lsnode prev,current,next;//note these changes throughout
    current = *head;//note use of asterisk to reference 
                    //object being changed 
    prev = NULL;
    next = NULL;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head = prev;
}


int main(void)
{
    lsnode head = create3();
    reverse2(&head);//passes address of object to be modified
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
 10
 20
 30
```